# GraphViz node ultra-wide node width mystery

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, graphviz

I'm auto-generating .dot files via a series of transformations. Everything works fine until I deploy the application. (A Node app deployed to Azure that uses a mix of server-side JS and F# in .Net.)
After deployment, all node widths are very wide - about 20x their normal size, so that a single node takes up about the width of the screen. (The text label size is normal - the remaining is whitespace.) I'm outputting SVG, but I tested image format and this happens regardless of output format. Height remains unaffected. I have no particular size or scaling settings specified on the graph.

I've copied the deployed /bin directory back to my dev machine, and running dot from there on the file generated by the server works just fine - so the intermediate dot digraph file is not the issue, but where the code is executing. I have also tried running "dot -c" on the server with no apparent change.

Does anyone know of a configuration, environment, or other issue that could result in the drastic widening of nodes (and therefore the entire document)?

thanks

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/glejeune/node-graphviz in your application?

Comment: No -- the node application shells out to my F# application, and my F# application shells out to Dot.exe.